# protractorJS chai - How do i use getText() to assert the text of elements within an array contains a string?

Tags: protractor, cucumber, chai, gherkin

I'm getting an error returned when trying to assert against the text found within an array of elements

```
 AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to include 'This profile exists already and has two places.'
```

i declared the webelement reference in a page object file

i created a step that contains some code to verify the text within an array of elements

This is the webelement reference declared in the page object:

```
get importErrorsList(){
    return element.all(by.css('[ng-if="error.error.detailMessage"]'));
}
```

This is how i try to check the text within the array of web elements

```
                directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList.getText().then(function(text) {         
                    console.log('test console output: ' + text);
                    expect(text).to.contain(errorText);
                    callback();
                });
```

actual: i get the assertion error

expected:
the test passes.

note that in the code for the steps, i have a `console.log` snippet, which outputs a string that *does* contain the string searching for: ***test console output: com.reputation.imex.imp.ImportException: This profile exists already and has two places. Using the CSV import is not supported for this profile***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me eventually:

`expect(directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList.getText()).to.eventually.contain(errorText).and.notify(callback);`

Answer (score 0):

`importErrorsList` returns `ElementArrayFinder`.

If the application may return only one element that match the css selecror change your method to:

```
get importErrorsList(){
    return element.all(by.css('[ng-if="error.error.detailMessage"]'));
}
```

But if it's fine for you to get `ElementArrayFinder` change your `expect` to:

`expect(text).to.deep.contain(errorText);`

Comment: This code still results in the same error:

`directoriesPageObj.importErrorsList.getText().then(function(text) {   
      //console.log('test console output: ' + text);
      
expect(text).to.deep.contain(errorText);

      callback();

     });`